# How can I access primary_key/id while building the Ecto changeset

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

I want to build some ancestry features with a materialized path.

So when I create the first item (it would probably get id of 1). the `ancestry` item would be `1/`. Then when I create an item that is the child of that, it would have `ancestry` of `1/2/` or `parent_ancestry + :id + /` but I can't access the :id in the changeset, is there any way to achieve this?

I expect:

```
changeset = Model.changeset(%Model{}, %{thing: "thing"})
{:ok, model} = Repo.insert(changeset)
%Model{id: 1, thing: "thing", ancestry: "1/"}

changeset2 = Model.changeset(%Model{}, %{thing: "thing2", parent_id: 1})
{:ok, model} = Repo.insert(changeset2)
%Model{id: 2, thing: "thing2", ancestry: "1/2/"} # I know how to grab the parent ancestry here, I know it's not just the parent_id. My issue is the current model's id
```